# SLES DHCP Dynamic DNS: Unable to add forward map...: not found

Tags: bind, lxc, isc-dhcp, dynamic-dns, sles11

I have a SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11.3 install running on Amazon EC2 based off the official AMI.

With DHCP and BIND configured (via yast) I'm having issues with Dynamic DNS.

When a client connects to the DHCP server I receive the error message:

```
Dec 31 04:26:41 ip-10-35-139-46 dhcpd: Unable to add forward map from XXXXXXX.containers.box to 192.168.2.8: not found
```

The DHCP and DNS servers are running on the same server, with the address 192.168.1.1 on a bridged interface connecting it to LXC's. The LXC's are set to DHCP off of 192.168.1.1. (and the DHCP logs would seem to confirm they're working correctly, they have functional internet access currently and are assigned addresses by the DHCP server)

The DNS server is also seemingly functional based off of dig commands (pasted below)

I'm running ISC dhcp-server 4.2.4.P2 and Bind 9.9.3P2.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Todd

Pasting my resolv.conf, named.conf, and dhcpd.conf files.

resolv.conf

```
### /etc/resolv.conf file autogenerated by netconfig!
#
# Before you change this file manually, consider to define the
# static DNS configuration using the following variables in the
# /etc/sysconfig/network/config file:
#     NETCONFIG_DNS_STATIC_SEARCHLIST
#     NETCONFIG_DNS_STATIC_SERVERS
#     NETCONFIG_DNS_FORWARDER
# or disable DNS configuration updates via netconfig by setting:
#     NETCONFIG_DNS_POLICY=''
#
# See also the netconfig(8) manual page and other documentation.
#
# Note: Manual change of this file disables netconfig too, but
# may get lost when this file contains comments or empty lines
# only, the netconfig settings are same with settings in this
# file and in case of a "netconfig update -f" call.
#
### Please remove (at least) this line when you modify the file!
search containers.box ec2.internal
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 172.16.0.23
```

---

dhcpd.conf

```
option domain-name "containers.box";
option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;
option routers 192.168.1.1;
default-lease-time 14400;
include "/etc/named.d/ToddKey";
ddns-update-style interim;
ignore client-updates;
ddns-updates on;
subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 {
  range 192.168.2.1 192.168.2.250;
  default-lease-time 14400;
  max-lease-time 172800;
  zone private.lan. { primary 192.168.1.1; key ToddKey; }
  zone 168.192.in-addr.arpa. { primary 192.168.1.1; key ToddKey; }
```

---

named.conf

```
# Copyright (c) 2001-2004 SuSE Linux AG, Nuernberg, Germany.
# All rights reserved.
#
# Author: Frank Bodammer, Lars Mueller <lmuelle@suse.de>
#
# /etc/named.conf
#
# This is a sample configuration file for the name server BIND 9.  It works as
# a caching only name server without modification.
#
# A sample configuration for setting up your own domain can be found in
# /usr/share/doc/packages/bind/sample-config.
#
# A description of all available options can be found in
# /usr/share/doc/packages/bind/misc/options.

options {

        # The directory statement defines the name server's working directory

        directory "/var/lib/named";

        # Write dump and statistics file to the log subdirectory.  The
        # pathenames are relative to the chroot jail.

        dump-file "/var/log/named_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/log/named.stats";

        # The forwarders record contains a list of servers to which queries
        # should be forwarded.  Enable this line and modify the IP address to
        # your provider's name server.  Up to three servers may be listed.

        #forwarders { 192.0.2.1; 192.0.2.2; };

        # Enable the next entry to prefer usage of the name server declared in
        # the forwarders section.

        #forward first;

        # The listen-on record contains a list of local network interfaces to
        # listen on.  Optionally the port can be specified.  Default is to
        # listen on all interfaces found on your system.  The default port is
        # 53.

        #listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; };

        # The listen-on-v6 record enables or disables listening on IPv6
        # interfaces.  Allowed values are 'any' and 'none' or a list of
        # addresses.

        listen-on-v6 { any; };

        # The next three statements may be needed if a firewall stands between
        # the local server and the internet.

        #query-source address * port 53;
        #transfer-source * port 53;
        #notify-source * port 53;

        # The allow-query record contains a list of networks or IP addresses
        # to accept and deny queries from. The default is to allow queries
        # from all hosts.

        #allow-query { 127.0.0.1; };

        # If notify is set to yes (default), notify messages are sent to other
        # name servers when the the zone data is changed.  Instead of setting
        # a global 'notify' statement in the 'options' section, a separate
        # 'notify' can be added to each zone definition.

        notify no;
        include "/etc/named.d/forwarders.conf";
};

# To configure named's logging remove the leading '#' characters of the
# following examples.
#logging {
#       # Log queries to a file limited to a size of 100 MB.
#       channel query_logging {
#               file "/var/log/named_querylog"
#                       versions 3 size 100M;
#               print-time yes;                 // timestamp log entries
#       };
#       category queries {
#               query_logging;
#       };
#
#       # Or log this kind alternatively to syslog.
#       channel syslog_queries {
#               syslog user;
#               severity info;
#       };
#       category queries { syslog_queries; };
#
#       # Log general name server errors to syslog.
#       channel syslog_errors {
#               syslog user;
#               severity error;
#       };
#       category default { syslog_errors;  };
#
#       # Don't log lame server messages.
#       category lame-servers { null; };
#};

# The following zone definitions don't need any modification.  The first one
# is the definition of the root name servers.  The second one defines
# localhost while the third defines the reverse lookup for localhost.

zone "." in {
        type hint;
        file "root.hint";
};

zone "localhost" in {
        type master;
        file "localhost.zone";
};

zone "0.0.127.in-addr.arpa" in {
        type master;
        file "127.0.0.zone";
};

# Include the meta include file generated by createNamedConfInclude.  This
# includes all files as configured in NAMED_CONF_INCLUDE_FILES from
# /etc/sysconfig/named

include "/etc/named.conf.include";
zone "private.lan" in {
        file "dyn/private.lan";
        type master;
        allow-update { key ToddKey; };
        allow-transfer { any; };
};
logging {
        category default { log_syslog; };
        channel log_syslog { syslog; };
};
zone "168.192.in-addr.arpa" in {
        allow-update { key ToddKey; };
        allow-transfer { any; };
        file "dyn/168.192.in-addr.arpa";
        type master;
};

# You can insert further zone records for your own domains below or create
# single files in /etc/named.d/ and add the file names to
# NAMED_CONF_INCLUDE_FILES.
# See /usr/share/doc/packages/bind/README.SUSE for more details.
```

---

As well as the system log of BIND starting:

```
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: starting BIND 9.9.3-P2 -t /var/lib/named -u named
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: built with '--prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--localstatedir=/var' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--includedir=/usr/include/bind' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--with-openssl' '--enable-threads' '--with-libtool' '--enable-runidn' '--with-libxml2=/usr' '--with-gssapi' 'CFLAGS=-fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -g -fno-strict-aliasing' 'LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib64'
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: ----------------------------------------------------
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: BIND 9 is maintained by Internet Systems Consortium,
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: Inc. (ISC), a non-profit 501(c)(3) public-benefit
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: corporation.  Support and training for BIND 9 are
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: available at https://www.isc.org/support
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: ----------------------------------------------------
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: adjusted limit on open files from 8192 to 1048576
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: found 4 CPUs, using 4 worker threads
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: using 4 UDP listeners per interface
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: using up to 4096 sockets
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: loading configuration from '/etc/named.conf'
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: using default UDP/IPv4 port range: [1024, 65535]
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: using default UDP/IPv6 port range: [1024, 65535]
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: no IPv6 interfaces found
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: listening on IPv4 interface lo, 127.0.0.1#53
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: listening on IPv4 interface lo, 127.0.0.2#53
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: listening on IPv4 interface eth0, 10.35.139.46#53
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: listening on IPv4 interface br0, 192.168.1.1#53
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: generating session key for dynamic DNS
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: sizing zone task pool based on 5 zones
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: set up managed keys zone for view _default, file 'managed-keys.bind'
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 10.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 16.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 17.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 18.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 19.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 20.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 21.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 22.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 23.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 24.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 25.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 26.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 27.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 28.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 29.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 30.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 31.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 64.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 65.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 66.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 67.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 68.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 69.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 70.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 71.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 72.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 73.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 74.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 75.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 76.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 77.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 78.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 79.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 80.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 81.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 82.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 83.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 84.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 85.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 86.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 87.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 88.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 89.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 90.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 91.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 92.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 93.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 94.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 95.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 96.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 97.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 98.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 99.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 100.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 101.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 102.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 103.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 104.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 105.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 106.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 107.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 108.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 109.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 110.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 111.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 112.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 113.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 114.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 115.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 116.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 117.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 118.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 119.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 120.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 121.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 122.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 123.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 124.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 125.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 126.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 127.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 0.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 127.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 254.169.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 2.0.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 100.51.198.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 113.0.203.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 255.255.255.255.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.IP6.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.IP6.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: D.F.IP6.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 8.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 9.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: A.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: B.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: automatic empty zone: 8.B.D.0.1.0.0.2.IP6.ARPA
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: command channel listening on 127.0.0.1#953
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: managed-keys-zone: loaded serial 0
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 42
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: zone 0.0.127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 42
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: zone 168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 2013123100
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: zone private.lan/IN: loaded serial 2013123100
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: all zones loaded
Dec 31 04:35:09 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: running
Dec 31 04:36:12 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: received control channel command 'reload'
Dec 31 04:36:12 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: loading configuration from '/etc/named.conf'
Dec 31 04:36:12 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: using default UDP/IPv4 port range: [1024, 65535]
Dec 31 04:36:12 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: using default UDP/IPv6 port range: [1024, 65535]
Dec 31 04:36:12 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: no IPv6 interfaces found
Dec 31 04:36:12 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: sizing zone task pool based on 5 zones
Dec 31 04:36:12 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: reloading configuration succeeded
Dec 31 04:36:12 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: reloading zones succeeded
Dec 31 04:36:12 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: all zones loaded
Dec 31 04:36:12 ip-10-35-139-46 named[25012]: running
```

---

And the full DHCP server log:

```
Dec 31 04:22:49 ip-10-35-139-46 dhcpd: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.2.4-P2
Dec 31 04:22:49 ip-10-35-139-46 dhcpd: Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
Dec 31 04:22:49 ip-10-35-139-46 dhcpd: All rights reserved.
Dec 31 04:22:49 ip-10-35-139-46 dhcpd: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Dec 31 04:22:49 ip-10-35-139-46 dhcpd: Not searching LDAP since ldap-server, ldap-port and ldap-base-dn were not specified in the config file
Dec 31 04:22:49 ip-10-35-139-46 dhcpd: Wrote 8 leases to leases file.
Dec 31 04:22:49 ip-10-35-139-46 dhcpd: Listening on LPF/br0/0e:a1:29:d9:32:41/192.168.0.0/16
Dec 31 04:22:49 ip-10-35-139-46 dhcpd: Sending on   LPF/br0/0e:a1:29:d9:32:41/192.168.0.0/16
Dec 31 04:22:49 ip-10-35-139-46 dhcpd: Sending on   Socket/fallback/fallback-net
Dec 31 04:26:40 ip-10-35-139-46 dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 22:a1:31:2e:29:d9 (XXXXXXX) via br0
Dec 31 04:26:41 ip-10-35-139-46 dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.2.8 to 22:a1:31:2e:29:d9 (XXXXXXX) via br0
Dec 31 04:26:41 ip-10-35-139-46 dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.2.8 (192.168.1.1) from 22:a1:31:2e:29:d9 (XXXXXXX) via br0
Dec 31 04:26:41 ip-10-35-139-46 dhcpd: DHCPACK on 192.168.2.8 to 22:a1:31:2e:29:d9 (XXXXXXX) via br0
Dec 31 04:26:41 ip-10-35-139-46 dhcpd: Unable to add forward map from XXXXXXX.containers.box to 192.168.2.8: not found
```

---

DNS Server dig test

```
dig google.com 192.168.1.1

; <<>> DiG 9.9.3-P2 <<>> google.com 192.168.1.1
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 51212
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 11, AUTHORITY: 13, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             127     IN      A       74.125.228.134
google.com.             127     IN      A       74.125.228.129
google.com.             127     IN      A       74.125.228.137
google.com.             127     IN      A       74.125.228.131
google.com.             127     IN      A       74.125.228.136
google.com.             127     IN      A       74.125.228.135
google.com.             127     IN      A       74.125.228.142
google.com.             127     IN      A       74.125.228.130
google.com.             127     IN      A       74.125.228.128
google.com.             127     IN      A       74.125.228.132
google.com.             127     IN      A       74.125.228.133

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.                       203245  IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
.                       203245  IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.                       203245  IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.                       203245  IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
.                       203245  IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
.                       203245  IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.                       203245  IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
.                       203245  IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
.                       203245  IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.                       203245  IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
.                       203245  IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
.                       203245  IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.                       203245  IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Dec 31 04:45:29 UTC 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 426

;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 6633
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;192.168.1.1.                   IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.                       10800   IN      SOA     a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2013123001 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 10 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Dec 31 04
```

---

ifconfig

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:C7:44:8A:7C:53
          inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:820 (820.0 b)  TX bytes:830 (830.0 b)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 22:00:0A:23:8B:2E
          inet addr:10.35.139.46  Bcast:10.35.139.63  Mask:255.255.255.192
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:333542 errors:0 dropped:3 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:271272 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:106476543 (101.5 Mb)  TX bytes:375013813 (357.6 Mb)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:399587 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:399587 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:380974099 (363.3 Mb)  TX bytes:380974099 (363.3 Mb)

vethqEZAM Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:C7:44:8A:7C:53
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:918 (918.0 b)  TX bytes:1244 (1.2 Kb)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved my problem.

I was using a different domain in my global options for my DHCP server 'containers.box' than what I had named my zone in my DNS server 'private.lan'. I thought since I was specifying what zone to update in the dhcpd.conf file it wouldn't matter, but it clearly does.

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

probleb is in iptables
You forgot to specify an option -o

Comment: When answering three year old questions, take the time to read other answers.